# Get custom taxonomies from multiple posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I've been looking around for half a day now but no success so far.

I've created a custom post type (recipe) and two custom taxonomies that go with it (type and cook). What I want is to be able to list all "cooks" from a group of recipes.

I can do it for a single recipe but I'm stuck with multiple ones.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please add some examples to it, which will better explain your situation and along with that can you also add the concerned codes.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty What I wanted is in fact to have a link of the cooks from a group of recipes in an unrodered list. I could get the cook from a single recipe using the `get_the_terms()` function but when it comes to retrieving cooks from multiple recipes, I'm stuck.

@Charles Clarkson works fine and does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each post add each term to a PHP associative array:

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    $term_objects = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_name );

    foreach ( $term_objects as $term_object ) {

        // Store term objects by term name.
        $terms_list[ $term_object->name ] = $term_object;
    }
}
```

Let's say *Bob* was listed as the cook on the first two recipes. When the first post is processed a field named `Bob` is added to  `$terms_list`. On the second post the `Bob` field is overwritten with the same information (a term object).

The result after looping through all posts is a list `key => values` where the keys are unique. *Bob*, for example, is only listed once.

Since you didn't provide any code or tell us what you wanted the output should look like, I made this example up using the [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) function to get the array of posts and used an unordered list to display the cooks names as links.

```
$cooks = wpse_125356_get_terms_for_posts( get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'recipe' ) ), 'cook' );

if ( $cooks ) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ( $cooks as $cook ) {

        $url = get_term_link( $cook );
        if ( is_wp_error( $url ) ) {
            echo "\t<li>{$cook->name}</li>\n";
        } else {
            echo "\t<li><a href='{$url}'>{$cook->name}</a></li>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n\n";
}


/**
 * Get all unique terms for an array of posts for a given taxonomy.
 *
 * @param array $posts An array of post objects.
 * @param string $taxonomy_name The name of the taxonomy to retrieve.
 * @return array An array term objects ordered by term name.
 */
function wpse_125356_get_terms_for_posts( array $posts, $taxonomy_name ) {

    $terms_list = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

        $term_objects = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_name );

        // $term_objects can also be boolean false or a WP_Error object.
        if ( is_array( $term_objects ) ) {
            foreach ( $term_objects as $term_object ) {

                // Store term objects by term name.
                $terms_list[ $term_object->name ] = $term_object;
            }
        }
    }

    // Sort term objects by term name.
    ksort( $terms_list );

    // Return a list of term objects, if any.
    return array_values( $terms_list );
}
```

Comment: What a good idea to store them by term name. This is exactly what I'm looking for and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.